# Batch error: | was not expected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I checked almost all the other questions regarding this issues, I've tried them all but still no success, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong that I get the error " | not expected at this time" when running.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LOGFILE=pathBackup.csv
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('time /t') DO set vtime2=%%i

IF NOT EXIST Logs mkdir Logs
echo DATE,TIME,HOSTNAME,CONNECTION,PATH > Logs\%LOGFILE%

FOR /F %%i in (clientList.txt) DO (

    set _tempus=%%i
    sc \\!_tempus! start remoteregistry > NUL
    set RegCommand=reg query "\\!_tempus!\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path

    FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%a in ('%RegCommand% ^| find "REG_"') do set vPath=%%c
    echo %date%,%vtime2%,!_tempus!,Successful,%vPath% >> Logs\%LOGFILE%
    sc \\!_tempus! stop remoteregistry > NUL
)

echo.
echo clientList.txt reading complete.
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo.
pause
```

The clientList.txt includes only hostnames / ip addresses to the remote computers I wannt to connect.

```
LABORATORY1-PC
BRANCH3
UnknownnamePC
192.168.0.3
```

Comment: You seem to know that you need to use delayed expansion for one variable but not the other one.

Comment: So should I disable the delayed expansion before the FOR /f "tokens.." ?

Comment: No. You need to use delayed expansion for all your variables because you are inside a code block.  All your variables should be !varname! instead of %varname% just like you did with your _tempus variable.

Comment: I don't want to be nitpicking - to be more precise normal `%` vars in a code block a evaluated only once when the block is entered. If the var is newly assigned a value inside the block you have to use DelayedExpansion with `!` or double; sometimes quadruple the `%%` in combination with a pseudo call.

Comment: You could do this whole batch file without using delayed expansion if you just used the FOR variables directly instead of assigning them to environmental variables.  Although I don't know where your `%vtime2% `variable is coming from.

Comment: Because the script is intended to make a backup of the SYSTEM path of the list of computers, this because I  will deploy an application to those remote computers that is still in beta so is known for us that it damages the system path... As far as I know, the command Path or echoing %path% returns the user/session path but not the system one.

Comment: the vtime2 variable came from:

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('time /t') DO set vtime2=%%i 

just pulled the current time to a variable so that I can do a full echo like I did in the end of the script, for logging purposes, it's being written in -csv format so I can panipulate it easily with excel

Comment: I see only one `|` symbol in your code which is properly escaped; hence until you show the content of `clientList.txt` and the value of variable `vtime2`, it is impossible to help you... please add any more information to the question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40246077/edit) your post...

Comment: OK I edited the post with the full script and an example of my clientlist.txt

Comment: Change `%RegCommand%` into `%%RegCommand%%` or `!RegCommand!`

Comment: For the love of god, remove `@echo off` while you're debugging, and CMD will *tell you where the error is*!

Comment: Thanks to you all guys you been so helpful, I'm glad that is my first question on this community and I got valuable help, I know the site ages ago but almost all my questions were already solved to date so never had to do a new one.... Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @aezaratec, delayed expansion is probably the most misunderstood concept of batch files and is probably asked a couple of times a day on StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how I would do it without using delayed expansion.

```
@echo off

set regpath=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
set regval=/v Path
set logfile=pathlog.txt

FOR /F "delims=" %%G in (clientList.txt) DO (
    sc \\%%G start remoteregistry > NUL
    FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%H in ('reg query "\\%%G\%regpath%" %regval% ^| find "REG_"') do (
        echo %date%,%time%,%%G,Successful,%%J >>logs\%LOGFILE%
    )
    sc \\%%G stop remoteregistry > NUL
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, this one woked like charm! I owe you a beer! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As is, the only problem in the code is the expansion of the `RegCommand` variable. As it is changed and readed inside the `for /f %%i` loop, you need delayed expansion to retrieve its value. As it is not used, the parser replaces the variable read with nothing (the value in the variable before entering the loop), so the command inside the `for` command starts directly with the pipe.

Changing from `%RegCommand%` to `!RegCommand!` (expanding the variable in the calling batch) or to `%%RegCommand%%` (to expand the variable in the spawn `cmd` instance) should solve the problem.

BUT it is a lot better not having to deal with it. The code in the Squashman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40247277/2861476) shows the correct way to code it, without the need for delayed expansion by directly usage of the `for` replaceable parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the code to the one suggested by Squashman, but also tried changing the variable to !RegCommand! and it also works, I owe you a beer mate! Cheers!